# How does one handle multiple modules/packages in python?

Tags: python, import, module, package

I've spent hours researching this problem, and I'm still baffled. Please find my ignorance charming.

I'm building a python program that will allow me to pit two AIs against each other in a game of battleship.

Here's my directory structure:

```
.
├── ais_play_battleship
│   ├── game.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── player.py
│   └── ship.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── tests
    └── ship_test.py

2 directories, 7 files
```

Currently, I'm trying to write `ship_test.py`, but I cannot seem to import `ais_play_battleship.ship`. I get the dreaded "ModuleNotFoundError"

Here's what my research has taught me about my problem:

- If you want to import python code from another directory, you should make that directory a package instead of a module. Therefore, I've placed an `__init__.py` file in the root of `ais_play_battleship`.
- Python will only search the directory python is launched from as well as the directory of the script you're running. Therefore, I've been trying to launch my tests by running `python3 tests/ship_tests.py` from the root directory.

Here are my specific questions:

- Why is the error a "ModuleNotFound" error? Shouldn't it be "PackageNotFound"?
- Am I correct to make ais_play_battleship a package?
- How can I keep my tests in a separate directory and still use the code in ais_play_battleship?

Please forgive me, as I'm not very good at asking questions on StackOverflow. Please tell me how I can improve.

Comment: I suspect that you've neglected to set your `path` to include `ais_play_battleship`.

Comment: Are you suggesting I do something like the following?
`import sys`
`sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')`
Also, I thought that if I was running the program from the parent directory, I didn't need to. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 11):

I am answering my own question, as I haven't yet received a satisfactory answer. The best resource I've found is [available here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#test-suite). In summary:

Python does NOT search the directory you run python from for modules. Furthermore, adding an `__init__.py` file to make a directory a package is not enough to make it visible to an instance of python running in another folder. You must also install that package. Therefore, the only two ways to access a module in another directory are:

1. Install the packaged module in site-packages (this requires the creation of a `setup.py` file and installation using `pip install .` More information is [available here.](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)
2. Modify path to resolve the module

I ended up settling with the second option, for reasons discussed below.

The first option requires one to reinstall the package at every change to a package. This is difficult on a constantly-changing codebase, but can be made easier by using build automation. However, I'd like to avoid this added complexity.

I shied away from the second option for a long time, because it seemed that modifying the path would require hard-coding the absolute path to my module, which is obviously unacceptable, as every developer would have to edit that path to fit their environment. However, [this guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#test-suite) provides a solution to this problem. Create a `./tests/context.py` file with the following contents:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

Then, in my `ship_test.py` module, I imported the context and the module I needed:

```
import context
import ais_play_battleship.ship
# (I include the submodule ship because ais_play_battleship itself does not have
# any attributes or methods, and the submodule ship is the only one I am testing
# in ship_test.py)
```

This fits my project better, because it works as expected without having to worry about installing my package (or the method by which my package was installed).

Comment: re:`"The first option requires one to reinstall the package at every change to a package. This is difficult on a constantly-changing codebase, but can be made easier by using build automation. However, I'd like to avoid this added complexity."`  For development, you can do what's called an "editable" install : `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem without relying on hacking about your `sys.path`, create a setup.py file and as a build step for your test runner, have it run `pip install .` first.  You might want to use a tool like `tox`.

In the top level directory:

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='ais_play_battleship')
```

tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py36, py37

[testenv]
deps=pytest
commands=
    pip install . --quiet
py.test -q
```

then run your tests (in this example we use tox to do this so that we can also configure how the test environment can be configured) : `tox`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not going to worry about tox at this point, I'm just concerned with understanding imports and modules and packages. What does `setup.py` do and why do I need it? What does `pip install .` do?

Comment: If you want a comprehensive answer, I would suggest reading this : https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  

Otherwise, the gist of it is that `pip` is just a python package manager, and `setup.py` is a magic file that the `pip` python package manager looks for when it wants to install a directory of code that an author wants to bundle together as a single "python package".  You can think of it as configuration for how to setup a set of files and subdirectories from some implicit project root directory declare and make modules available to your python PATH.

Comment: I read the page you linked to, and it was helpful in solving my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I spoke too soon. I'm still having problems. I posted my own answer because I thought I had it figured out, but I was wrong. Then, I tried exploring tox and I haven't got that to work either. Currently the error I'm dealing with reports `no module named ais_play_battleship`. Here's [the full ouput of tox.](https://pastebin.com/c26638xS)

Answer (score 1):

Run `tests/ship_test.py` as a module

```
python -m tests.ship_test
```